# Passing CoreData keys to new ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am working on one part of my app which will function as a journal for the user, in which they can add an entry, then review or delete them afterwards. I followed a few Swift tutorials for CoreData and I have confirmed that the CoreData setup is working. However, I am having trouble getting values to pass to the `UIViewController` that will display the journal after already being saved. In one configuration I had tried it displayed no data, in another the data would stay the same no matter what entry selected, and in the setup below, this line `journalEntryViewer.journalViewerTextView.text = journalTextToPass` returns "found nil when unwrapping optional value."
Here is the code for the `UITableViewController` that acts as the list:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class JournalCollectionViewer: UITableViewController {
    var JournalEntry = [NSManagedObject]()
    var journalTextToPass:String!
    var journalTitleToPass:String!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "JournalEntry")
    do {
        let results =
            try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)

        JournalEntry = results as! [NSManagedObject]
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
// MARK: - Table view data source

@IBOutlet weak internal var journalCollectionTable: UITableView!


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return JournalEntry.count
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
               cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell =
        tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("JournalCell")

    let entry = JournalEntry[indexPath.row]

    cell!.textLabel!.text =
        entry.valueForKey("journalDate") as? String
    return cell!
}
    func selectedTableCell(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let entry = self.JournalEntry[indexPath.row]

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ShowEntryViewer", sender: entry)
}
// MARK: - Navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowEntryViewer" {
        let journalEntryViewer = segue.destinationViewController as! JournalEntryViewer
        journalEntryViewer.self.navigationItem.title = journalTitleToPass
        journalEntryViewer.journalViewerTextView.text = journalTextToPass
    }
}
}
```

In the Swift file for the viewer (`journalEntryViewer`), all I have done is declared the class and the UITextView. Needless to say, I am at a loss. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Core Data is an object persistence solution, so in almost all cases what you should be passing is NSManagedObject instances, or even better NSManagedObject subclass instances.  Having set up your Core Data model, Xcode can generate these subclasses for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign value to the `IBOutlet` object in the `prepareForSegue` method that time it is not initialized, so you need to pass the string object and assign that string object to the `journalViewerTextView` in the `viewDidLoad`of `JournalEntryViewer`.

First declare two instance var in the `JournalEntryViewer` like this

```
var journalTitle: String?
var journalText: String?
```

Now use this var in `viewDidload`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.title = journalTitle
    self.journalViewerTextView.text = journalTitle
}
```

Now pass this `journalTitle` and `journalText` in the `prepareForSegue` method of `JournalCollectionViewer`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowEntryViewer" {
        let journalEntryViewer = segue.destinationViewController as! JournalEntryViewer
        journalEntryViewer.journalTitle = journalTitleToPass
        journalEntryViewer.journalText = journalTextToPass
    }
}
```

**New Edit:**

Problem with your code is you have not used delegate method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` instead of you are using something else `selectedTableCell` that is wrong try to implement delegate method of UITableView

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let entry = self.JournalEntry[indexPath.row]
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ShowEntryViewer", sender: entry)
}
```

Now you are passing entry object so change your `prepareForSegue` like this

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowEntryViewer" {
        let journalEntryViewer = segue.destinationViewController as! JournalEntryViewer
        let entry = sender as! NSManagedObject
        journalEntryViewer.journalTitle = entry.valueForKey("journalDate") as? String
        journalEntryViewer.journalText = entry.valueForKey("journalEntryText") as? String
    }
}
```

Comment: This successfully grabs the information, but once I select one journal entry, it won't change on selection of another. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Can  you give me more detail about your issue?

Comment: If I tap on one journal entry (say one that says "Hello"), the title and text will appear as it should in the `JournalEntryViewer`, but if I tap on another with different data, the `JournalEntryViewer` still displays the one that says "Hello".

Comment: please add the code of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` in your question.

Comment: Okay that seems like it will work better but on row selection I get output & crash "Could not cast value of type UITableViewCell  to NSManagedObject" on the line `let entry = sender as! NSManagedObject`

Comment: your segue is connected with `UITableViewCell`, remove that one and create one that connect `JournalCollectionViewer` controller to `JournalEntryViewer` controller and give the same segue identifier.

Comment: This works! Thank you so much for your help! Marking as answer

Comment: You wouldn't perchance know how to sort the table so the newest entry is at the top?

Comment: Don't understand what you want, If you want to sort the Core Data object then you can use `NSSortDescriptor` with fetch request.

Comment: That was it. Thanks again!